# Why puppeteer page.goto() hangs?

Tags: puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I'm running `puppeteer` in an `alpine-chrome` container with sandboxing, everything is done exactly as the docs suggest. And I've created a whole bunch of different puppeteer-fueled servers.

I'm launching Puppeteer without any arguments, except `headless: false`.

Why is `await page.goto()` method so problematic? It keeps giving me all kinds of non-sensical problems.

I'm always doing this:

```
await page.goto('https://my-url.com/something', {
  waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
  timeout: 0
})
```

Right now it just randomly hangs. Nothing happens, code execution just stops there. All I see is that CPU utilization hits the roof and then down to slightly-elevated levels, comparing to the properly-ongoing execution. 90% of time the `goto` doesn't elevate CPU utilization at all. Same page, same server, hangs randomly within the same script execution.

Why is this hapening? Do I have to put `setTimeout` and `try-catch` statements all over my code around each `page.goto()` method? It feels like I'm using `puppeteer` fundamentally incorrect, because this behaviour doesn't make sense.

Sorry for vague question, I don't understand what kind of information would be helpful here.

Comment: I dont know why that is happening either but i always do
 ```await Promise.All([
page.waitForNavigation(),
page.goto(url)
])```
instead of passing `waitUntil` property to the `page.goto()` method as an argument. That works nice for me.

Comment: `page.goto` should work fine. Is this really all of your code? Which URL are you using? Do you have an [unnecessary `waitForNavigation` call later on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66177812/puppeteer-never-completely-loads-the-page/66179257#66179257)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the goto method is throwing you errors. Therefore it's important to review this tidbit of info from puppeteer documentation -

https://devdocs.io/puppeteer/index#pagegotourl-options

> page.goto will throw an error if:
>
> -there's an SSL error (e.g. in case of self-signed certificates).
>
> -target URL is invalid. the timeout is exceeded during navigation.
>
> -the remote server does not respond or is unreachable.
>
> -the main resource failed to load.

I would also recommend trying networkidle0 and maybe not passing a timeout parameter. It's odd you're having this issue as normally its not page.goto() function giving me issues but working with the selectors.

Answer (score 0):

It hangs because you have disabled timeout by setting `timeout: 0` option and it is waiting until there are no more than 2 network connections for at least 500 ms. You can set timeout option in milliseconds. The following will throw timeout error if `page.goto()` is not completed within 30 seconds.

```
await page.goto('https://my-url.com/something', {
  waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
  timeout: 30000,
})
```

Please refer to puppeteer documentation at https://devdocs.io/puppeteer/index#pagegotourl-options .